# Tags de Base de Dados

Tags: debate, status-pronto, tags

Boas, Acho que apenas precisamos da tag banco/base-de-dados, atualmente temos essa e várias outras:

> db,
>
> bd,
>
> banco-de-dados,
>
> base-de-dados,
>
> database,

E outras

Comment: A [tag:dbase] é específica de um produto, o resto parece ser sinônimo, exceto o etc.Pelo menos uma já é sinônimo.

Comment: Você deseja criar outra tag relacionada a banco de dados? Seria para generalizar o assunto?

Comment: base-de-dados existe mesmo?

Comment: penso que seria melhor haver uma só ao invés de haver estas todas, uma vez que são da mesma coisa..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Concordo, tanto que já apliquei as modificações `:P`. Me parece haver consenso que são todas sinônimos.

[base-de-dados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/base-de-dados) já estava como sinônimo de [banco-de-dados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/banco-de-dados) desde setembro do ano passado. Daí eu inclui agora também como sinônimo [db](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/db), [bd](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bd) e [database](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/database).